# How can i read text file and store text values in data base in java?

Tags: java, io

I have text file  which i have read once user upload, how can i read using java code, can any one give some suggestion which would very helpful to me

sample file looks like below

```
SNR   Name
1     AAR
2     BAT
3     VWE
```

Comment: There are many ways to read this file. You can read it line-by-line and handle tokens from each line separately, or word-by-word assuming each line will have same amount of words. All this can be achieved with Scanner class. Take a look at its documentation to get more detailed info.

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern is to use

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)) ) {
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // process the line to insert in database.
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is use Scanner() object

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("myFile.txt"));
```

use

```
boolean hasNext = sc.hasNext();
```

to know if there are more items in the file

and

```
String item = sc.next();
```

to get items secuentially.

I attach the documentation (it provides very good code examples)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use BufferedReader to read file line by line. 
So, even if your file is too big, then also it will read line by line only. It won't load entire file. Declaration will be similar to this.

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));
And 
you can use command

while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) { .....// process
}

to read file till end. 
Obviously, you have to use seperator in file to split the records in each line. And store accordingly in java objects. 
After that you can store in DB through DAO.